# instead of incrementing +1 it will give the total

Tags: jquery, ajax

If I click the button which has a value of 'c' it should increment by one, but instead of incrementing by one it gives me the total of all the values of 'c', which is equal to 2 since I have two 'c' values. Can somebody help?

#### html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.btn').click(function() {
  var value = $(this).attr("name", "one").val();
  var value2 = $(this).attr("name", "two").val();
  $.post("myFile.php", { one:value, two:value2 }, function(data){ 
  $('#divs') .html(data);
});
});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="1">number one
<button class="btn" name="one" value="w">A</button>
<button class="btn" name="one" value="w">B</button>
<button class="btn" name="one" value="c">C</button>
<div id="divs"></div>
</div>
<div id="2">number two
<button class="btn" name="two" value="w">A</button>
<button class="btn" name="two" value="c">B</button>
<button class="btn" name="two" value="w">C</button>
<div id="divs"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### myFile.php

```
<?php
$count = 0;
$first= $_POST['one'];
$second= $_POST['two'];
if($first== 'c'){
    $count++;
}
if($second=='c'){
    $count++;
}
echo $count;
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's important first to identify if the problem is in the client-side Javascript, or in the server-side PHP. Also, all modern browsers have debuggers (usually accessible by pressing the `F12` key on the keyboard) which you can use to step through the Javascript and see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var name = $this.attr('name');
        var thisValue = $this.val();
        var postData = {};
        ['one','two'].forEach(function(x) {
            data[x] = name == x ? thisValue : null;
        });
        $.post("myFile.php", postData, function(data){ 
            $('#divs').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

P.S. But i still can't understand your approach why do you need that

Comment: I've made some changes to your code; if the edits are too much, I'll undo them.